# Using pyqgis with existing ArcGIS files

Tags: pyqgis, esri-grid-format

I'm pretty new to GIS.  I have some files that seem to have been created using ArcGIS (I got them from here http://www.fao.org/ag/againfo/resources/en/glw/GLW_dens.html).

I would like to do some analysis on these maps, preferably using python.  I'm wondering if it's possible to use pyqgis to do this kind of thing.

I'm really just looking for some info to get me started.
e.g.

- Is it possible to import these files into a pyqgis application?
- Are there any tutorials that might help me get started?

---

The file types I see are .lyr, .aux, .avl, .dat, .nit, .adf

Here's a specific example of what I'd like to do.  Say I have two maps (map A and map B).  I think these are raster images, and let's say that the "colour" in a given cell in map A measures quantity qA. And likewise for map B.  Something simple I'd like to do is to produce a third map (map C) whose cells have quantities given by qC = qA*qB.

Comment: Can you say what sort of analysis you would like to do?

Comment: What sort of files are they?

Comment: I edited the original post to include a concrete example of something I might try to do.  Consider me a reasonably good programmer, but I have no ArcGIS or GIS experience.

Comment: Also, I'd rather use something open/free (e.g. qgis/pyqgis)